# Iterating an Array in Python using the brentq Function

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, mathematical-optimization

I am having trouble iterating every element of an array using the `brentq` function. `q` in the defined function below is a FITS file array, and we are using every element in this array as inputs to run through the `brentq`function in order to solve for `T`.

Essentially, my problem lies in not particularly knowing where or how to implement the appropriate `for` loop to iterate the function over every element of `q`.

Any suggestions on how to go about this problem?

```
def f(T,q,coeff1,coeff2,coeff3):
    return q*const3 - ((exp(const2/T)-1)/(exp(const/T)-1))

a = brentq(f, 10, 435.1, args=(q,4351.041,4262.570,0.206))
print a

newhdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(a)
newhdulist = fits.HDUList([newhdu])
newhdulist.writeto('Temp21DCOT.fits')
```

**Further explanation:** The basis of what I'm trying to do is to use `brentq` to solve for temperature values using the intensity values of our initial array (our FITS file).

The equation is derived from a ratio of two wavelengths of Plank's Equation, so `q = B_1/B_2` if we want to be true to physics, where every element in `q` are intensity values. `brentq` would solve this analytically insolvable equation for `T` (temperature) for every element in `q`, and make a new temperature array of the same size as `q`. In other words, I am trying to solve for the temperature of every pixel in a FITS file using Plank's Equation.

Note: I re-posted this to clarify the problem in a more efficient manner.

Comment: The function argument names do not match the variable names in the *return expression* of ```f```.   Are you using ```scipy.optimize.brentq```?

Comment: Yes, precisely. I imported scipy.optimize as brentq.

Comment: Your function takes 5 arguments.  You are passing 4 values in the ```brentq```  ```args``` argument - it looks like *```f.q```* in your example is 1.  are you asking how to iterate over an array and substitute the one in ```args(1, 4351.041 ...``` of the example with values from the array?

Comment: Yes, so we are only iterating the two-dimensional array into first argument in `arg(q,...)`, the rest are constants.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you having problems with iteration, or with efficiency?

This iteration works for me:

```
In [485]: from scipy import optimize

In [486]: def f(T,q,coeff1,coeff2,coeff3):
        return q*coeff3 - ((np.exp(coeff2/T)-1)/(np.exp(coeff1/T)-1))
        # corrected the coeff use

In [487]: q=np.linspace(1,3,10)
# q range chosen to avoid the different signs ValueError

In [488]: A=[optimize.brentq(f, 10, 435.1, args=(i,4351.041,4262.570,0.206),full_output=True) for i in q]

In [489]: A
Out[489]: 
[(55.99858839149886, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa861284c>),
 (64.14621536172528, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa861286c>),
 (72.98658083834341, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa861288c>),
 (82.75638321495505, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa86128ac>),
 (93.73016750496367, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa86128cc>),
 (106.25045004489637, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa86128ec>),
 (120.76612665626851, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa861290c>),
 (137.88917389176325, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa861292c>),
 (158.4854607193551, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa861294c>),
 (183.82941862839408, <scipy.optimize.zeros.RootResults at 0xa861296c>)]

In [490]: [a[1].iterations for a in A]
Out[490]: [8, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 9, 8, 10]
```

In the `brentq` docs `f` returns one value, for one set of `args`.  There are some solvers, such as the `ode` ones, that let you define a function that takes a vector variable, and returns a matching vector derivative.  It doesn't look like this root finder allows that.  So you are stuck with iterating over the `args` values, and solving for each case.  I wrote the iteration as a list comprehension.  Other iteration formats are possible (for loop etc).  We might even be able the wrap this `brentq` call in a function that could be passed through `np.vectorize`.  But that is still going to be a iteration with minor time savings.

---

There are various ways of handling a multidimensional array.  One simple one is to `flatten` the input, do the 1d iteration, and then reshape the result.  For example:

```
In [517]: q1=q.reshape(2,5)

In [518]: q1
Out[518]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  1.22222222,  1.44444444,  1.66666667,  1.88888889],
       [ 2.11111111,  2.33333333,  2.55555556,  2.77777778,  3.        ]])

In [519]: np.array([optimize.brentq(f, 10, 435.1, args=(i,4351.041,4262.570,0.206)) for i in q1.flat]).reshape(q1.shape)
Out[519]: 
array([[  55.99858839,   64.14621536,   72.98658084,   82.75638321,
          93.7301675 ],
       [ 106.25045004,  120.76612666,  137.88917389,  158.48546072,
         183.82941863]])
```

I left off the `full_output` flag, since that adds complications.

Comment: Would this be the same procedure to do in a two-dimensional array? Because that's what `q` is, unfortunately.