# Vectorizing root finding in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, vectorization, mathematical-optimization

I need to run a function that finds the root of an equation that depends on one parameter over a large set of data (the real equation is much more complicated but formally equivalent).

```
def f(x):
    return numpy.optimize.brentq(lambda y:numpy.exp(-abs(x)*y)-y,0,1)
```

Is it convenient to vectorize it?
I tried to use `numpy.vectorize(f)` that works fine, but I think at the same speed of a python for loop.

Is there some kind of manual vectorization to better exploit the power of numpy array computation?

Comment: `numpy.vectorize` is a wrapper over a for loop, so it is useless in your case. The issue here is that the function `brentq` is written only for scalars, as discussed in another [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31364043/iterating-an-array-in-python-using-the-brentq-function). As suggested there, you are better off with a simple `for` list comprehension.

Comment: I am not sure if it can help, but you may try to play around with `scipy.optimize.fsolve` since it accepts vectorized input.

Comment: see also https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/7242

Answer (score 2):

If it's just a single parameter function, you can just interpolate the inverse function (tabulate x and y, interpolate x vs y, evaluate the interpolator at target values of y).

And no, manual vectorization won't let you avoid a python loop (unless you want to hack on a compiled level and wrap a C level loop around the compiled part of either brentq or fsolve --- and even that is likely slower than interpolating the inverse function.)